# How to limit max rows in select query by key

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have

```
  ID      ID2      Amount
  -------- -------- ------
  01       02           20
  01       03           30
  02       04           40
  02       06           30
  03       05           70
  03       06           60
  03       07           60
  04       08          100
  04       09          110
```

I want to query the data above into 2 resultset (return max 5 rows) which are:

result 1:

```
ID1      ID2      Amount
  -------- -------- ------
  01       02           20
  01       03           30
  02       04           40
  02       06           30
```

result 2:

```
ID1      ID2      Amount
  -------- -------- ------
  03       05           70
  03       06           60
  03       07           60
  04       08          100
  04       09          110
```

How should I construct my query?

Comment: What’s the logic behind the rows you choose? Maybe you are looking for the NTILE function to split your data in half?

Comment: I want to write the data into files where it needs to be grouped by ID1. Each of the file limited to max 5 rows

Comment: But your second result set isn’t grouped by ID1. It has multiple IDs

Comment: ID1 (03) having 3 rows where result 1 has already 4 rows, hence ID1 (03) need to be in result 2.

Comment: Now each result set has multiple IDs. Is the idea to group the result set into 5 rows ordered by ID1? How would you handle sets where the ID1 could straddle two sets? What’s the purpose?

Comment: yes.. I need to group the result set into max 5 rows ordered by ID1, each result set can have multiple sets of IDs.

Comment: Is this a paging thing? You want to display up to 5 rows at a time but avoid display ID1 across page breaks? Do you need to handle cases where ID1 would exceed 5 rows?

Comment: What you are asking for is called pagination... just search for it

Answer (score 0):

use `row_number()` to generate a sequential no. `(row_number() over (order by ID1) - 1) / 5 + 1` will gives you set of 5 per each result

```
; WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT result_no = (row_number() over (order by ID1) - 1) / 5 + 1,
           ID1, ID2, Amount
    FROM   yourtable
)
SELECT *
FROM   CTE
WHERE  result_no = @result_no
```